# Advantage of computing map.end() outside the loop

Tags: c++, performance, stl, iterator

I recently came across the following code.

```
std::map<int, int> m;

// insert into the map

std::map<int, int>::iterator endOfMap = m.end();
for(std::map<int, int>::iterator itr = m.begin(); itr != endOfMap; ++itr) {

}
```

Is there any advantage of computing endOfMap beforehand over the below?

```
for(std::map<int, int>::iterator itr = m.begin(); itr != m.end(); ++itr)
```

**Note:** 

The code I saw was a map of string to custom object, with millions of elements.

Comment: Well they would probably be so close in computation speed, but lets take the first example, the first one already computes the function call and does whatever it needs to, to endOfMap. the 2nd example in the termination condition it will be calling the m.end() function multiple times then check whether they are equal or not. Rather than just check if they are not equal and not calling the function multiple times.

Comment: You are talking about O(end()) + O(equality checking) vs. O(equality checking) in the for loop iterations.

Comment: The performance degradation from map's data memory allocation will outweigh any improvement from calling end() outside the loop!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't know the implementation of `map`, you can assume that making the assignment before the loop saves the overhead of calling `end()` each time through the loop.

But how much is that overhead? We already know that `end()` is implicitly inline, since it's a template function; if the code is simple enough, the compiler is highly likely to remove the function call overhead. The C++ standard guarantees that `end()` is an O(1) function, which means it's probably not too complex. If `end()` is simply returning a member of the object with no other computations, there might be absolutely no savings for copying it to a local variable!

On the other hand, this is a prime example of an optimization that doesn't cost you anything. If you get in the habit of doing this for every `for` loop you write, it doesn't hurt and once in a great while it might help. I've even seen the assignment done in the first segment of the `for` loop rather than on a line of its own.

Comment: Thank you :). From @Alejandro's comment below, I think the compiler is going to optimize this anyway?

Comment: But are all template functions inline?

Comment: @ThirupathiThangavel yes they are, because they're defined within the class declaration. You'll notice that all the code for a template function is part of the header file; if there are any functions that are in a .cpp file they must be in a base class instead.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any advantage of computing endOfMap beforehand over the below?

The only advantage, *that I can see*, will be the reduced cost of calling `std::map::end()` in every iteration of the loop. The difference is most likely going to be very little. You can only find it out by iterating over a `map` that has a HUGE number of elements in it. Even though the cost of calling `std::map::end()` is guaranteed by the standard to be `O(1)`, calling it millions of times may add noticeable cost to a function/program.

Comment: @songyuanyao it is not always O(n) constant time. The underlying implementation could have a pointer that is constantly keeping track of the last element. Unless you know for a fact that it doesn't keep track of this and just waits till the end and traverses.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI I meant `std::map::end()` always costs constant time itself; this is required by the standard.

Comment: @songyuanyao yes, but does the map keep track of the last element before the function call m.end? If so then it would just be O(1) in locating the last element. And that m.end() just possibly returns the pointer to that last element?

Comment: @OmidCompSCI That's might be a means of implementation, `std::map` is usually implemented by red–black tree. The implementation just has to guarantee that required by standard.

Comment: @songyuanyao okay got it! Thanks.

Comment: I'd imagine that any optimizing compiler would be able to hoist the call outside of the loop and preserve the value in a register assuming that there's enough visibility for the compiler to prove that the value won't change. [Here's an example](https://godbolt.org/g/ucC2Pe)

Answer (score 0):

It saves you a function call on each iterations, but considering that the map.end() is pretty light-weight method, you won't see a difference unless you are calling this function million times a second.